# How can I make Photoshop always open a new document with the same settings?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I *always* want to open a new document with the same size, resolution, colourmode etc. Photoshop annoyingly defaults to the clipboard etc. Is there any way to make the New dialog always open with my defaults?

Comment: Well, if you make a preset with specific settings, you can select that preset with 2 clicks.

Comment: I demonstrate the same on your behalf..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may look like rather long, but aside from the making of the preset, I tried to make it pretty detailed <sub>(You might be able to follow by just looking at the images)</sub>

---

**Making your own Preset:**

1. Start making a new document <sup>(Hotkey: Ctrl+N)</sup> with the settings that you want.
2. Use the (`Save Preset...`) button.
3. Name your preset and press Ok.

Preset is done and can be found from the preset list from now on.

---

**Making the Action:**

1. Open the Actions window <sup>(Hotkey: alt+F9)</sup>

   Make a new folder <sub>(very optional)</sub>

   [image]
2. Make a new Action

   [image]

   Set the name and other details for this action <sub>(can be changed
   later)</sub>

   When you press (`Record`) the recording will start.  <sup>When
   you're recording *don't* rush, it doesn't matter how long it takes
   for you to record the action</sup>

   [image]
3. Start making a new document <sup>(Hotkey: ctrl+N)</sup>

   Select the Preset that you've made and press OK. [image]
4. In the Action window press the Stop button.

   [image]
5. The action is done and just for reference. Here's what the action
   includes: [image]

So, when Action is done you can start it my pressing the play icon in the Action window or by using the assigned hotkey.

### -----

You could indeed make action where you don't start by making a preset and in #3 you would set the document settings that you want and press OK.

The thing about actions is that it takes longer for an action to be executed the more stuff you stick into the action.. Even though the action is not long in this case, it does split the stuff that the action has to do by about half.

Plus you can use the preset outside the action as well. This gives some freedom if you want to for example temporarily make the same document with another Color Profile.

Comment: @Lollero I'd probably take this one step further and use the Scripts Event Manager to always run the action any time a new file is created. No F-key required.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Hmmn.. I actually wouldn't. Well, not with the scenario that I'm thinking about. Maybe if I seriously _always_ had to make the same type of document with no other settings in between, then it would work. It's a bit esier to use different hotkey to make special type of document and use another hotkey to make another type of document rather than to go disable scripts whenever you have to make different type of document.

Comment: On another note, I've always hoped that photoshop actions would have more freedom with the hotkeys and then warn you if you're attempting to use hotkey that overlaps other hotkeys already used by photoshop.

Comment: Well, that *was* the question. In my own work, I'd never do such a thing, but if I literally always wanted the same settings, that is what I'd do.

Comment: @Lollero as far as the hotkeys are concerned, that's a real good point, and worth dropping in the feature request box (which they do read) on the Adobe site. Might be a quick fix for them to incorporate, although I've been surprised by them often enough. What seems simple on the surface sometimes turns out to be very complex under the hood.

Comment: @AlanGilbertson Right, That's true.. I guess I just read between the lines asuming that theres no way that someone would actually always use exactly the same document settings. Then again, people do more absurd things..  :) ( I'm gonna +1 your comment about the scripts event manager to make it stand out from all this chit chat )

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is save your desired document settings in **preset** for future use.

Please see these screenshot they are self explanatory

[image]

---

[image]

---

you can select that preset which you have made earlier from the drop down for every time you need those same settings.

[image]

Hope this will help...

Comment: Ok. I guess there's no better solution than this, so I'll accept it.

Comment: You need something better than this :o in-case you found something please post it here so we can know also..

Comment: @fredley You can make action where you basically record making a new document using a preset and then set a hotkey for that. It would allow you to do exactly what you want by pressing a hotkey that would be something like ctrl+F3. More about actions: ( http://veerle-v2.duoh.com/blog/comments/creating_a_photoshop_action/ )

Comment: @Lollero That sounds great, can you set it up as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know how to fix this. Just go to edit > purge > clipboard.

It happened to me too, but turns out for some reason, I had something in my clipboard, so whenever I made a new file, it automatically thought I wanted to see the clipboard thing. Purging it reset it.